# WPF Virtualizing a Canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, virtualization

We have a series of rectangles produced inside a Canvas and they are nested in this order ScrollView>Canvas>VirtualizingStackPanel>Rectangles in the XAML.

There seems to be little information on Microsoft about under what senarios Virtualization is supported, and in cases where it isn't no error is thrown, it merely treats it like a standard StackPanel.

Given that our view has roughly 60 rectangles on the screen at any one time out of a total of about 800 on the whole canvas the loading times of about 5 minutes are unacceptably slow.

We have already tryed removing the ScrollView to no effect ( other than removing the scroll bars the performance didn't improve), and removing some of the other nesting elements, the net effect seems to be either nothing is displayed, or its displayed but still slow.

The best solution I've found so far a sample piece of free ware code VirtualizedCanvas but its very very limited and doesn't support anything nested inside it, infact the only input it takes is a collection of UI Elements.

This solution basically ignores the databinding and requires a you to pass a completed Canvas back to it, this renders all our existing code and converters pretty useless, and would be major rework to implement.

Is there a way to simply clip the Virtualize the Canvas to only draw our 60 on screen items?

Comment: I've asked a similar question on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126230/resources-and-guides-to-ui-virtualization-in-wpf