# WPF : TreeView virtualization not working

Tags: wpf, treeview, virtualization, ui-virtualization

What can stop a TreeView from virtualizing if the TreeView is set up as follows?

```
<TreeView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
    <TreeView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemsPanel>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style
            TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter
                Property="IsExpanded"
                Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

I have one that is not virtualizing, when i expand the nodes (and use snoop to check) i have all of the TreeViewItems being created. I am wondering if there is some combination of containers that would prevent the TreeView from virtualizing its content. (like hosting it in a StackPanel for example)

Comment: This post may be of some help in virtualization customization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126230/resources-and-guides-to-ui-virtualization-in-wpf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was with the styling. After some research we found that there was an unnamed style targeting the TreeView (i.e. one with `DataType={x:Type TreeView}` without an `x:Key`) and one targetting the `TreeViewItem` in our App.xaml (or equivalent) It was overriding the `ControlTemplate` for each respectively.

These styles did not have the triggers to set the `ItemsPanel` to a `VirtualizingStackPanel` and had no mention of any virtualization. When the styles are removed the TreeView works fine. Even though the local properties set the `ItemsPanel` and the `VirtualizingStackPanel.Isvirtualizing="True"` on the `TreeView` these properties were not being propogated to the `TreeViewItems` so the top level of the TreeView would virtualize whilst the sub categories would not (as their virtualization behaviour was dependant on the `TreeViewItem`)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. In my case, the initial size of the TreeView was not limited (TreeView is within a popup). Therfore, the virtualization panel initialized all controls for the first time.

Setting the MaxHeigt of the TreeView to 1000 solvend the problem.

Comment: Add Virtualization like IsVirtualization = true and Mode = Recycle  and set the max Height  in Tree view. then it works perfectly in my case.Thanks